# Calling a method is giving me code and not the value (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, methods, console

basically I have created an object with a method which adds several attributes in the object together. But when I try and call the method to the console log it fires out the code (which is a if statement) to me instead of the value which I was hoping it would return, so I am confused! 
Why is this happening ?
Code Below:

```
var Granite = function(ty, gr, th, wi, le, ed, ad){
    this.type = ty;
    this.group = gr;
    this.thickness = th;
    this.width = wi;
    this.length = le;
    this.edgeProfile = ed;
    this.addOns = ad;
    this.groupPrice = function(){
        if (thickness === 20){
            switch(group)
            {
            case 1:
              return 160;
              break;
            case 2:
              return 194;
              break;
            case 3:
              return 244;
              break;
            case 4:
              return 288;
              break;
            case 5:
              return 336;
              break;
            case 6:
              return 380;
              break;
            default:
              return 380;
            }
        }else{
            switch(group)
            {
            case 1:
              return 200;
              break;
            case 2:
              return 242;
              break;
            case 3:
              return 305;
              break;
            case 4:
              return 360;
              break;
            case 5:
              return 420;
              break;
            case 6:
              return 475;
              break;
            default:
              return 475;
            }
        }   
    }
    this.price = function(){
        if(length <= 2000 && length > 1000){
            return ((edgeProfile + groupPrice)*2) - addOns;
        }else if(length <= 3000 && length > 2000){
            return ((edgeProfile + groupPrice)*3) - addOns;         
        }else if(length <= 4000 && length > 3000){
            return ((edgeProfile + groupPrice)*4) - addOns;         
        }else if(length <= 5000 && length > 4000){
            return ((edgeProfile + groupPrice)*5) - addOns;         
        }
    }
}

var granite1 = new Granite("Rosa Porrino", 1, 30, 400, 3200, 30.05, 86.18);

console.log(granite1.groupPrice);
```

It returns the full if statement within the groupPrice method to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling the method but providing reference of function to console,log(). In JavaScript you need use '()' to call a function.

this will surely work `console.log(granite1.groupPrice());`

In side this.price

use  `this.groupPrice()`. instead of `groupPrice`

Modified this,price Method

```
 this.price = function(){
        if(length <= 2000 && length > 1000){
            return ((this.edgeProfile + this.groupPrice())*2) - addOns;
        }else if(length <= 3000 && length > 2000){
            return ((this.edgeProfile + this.groupPrice())*3) - addOns;         
        }else if(length <= 4000 && length > 3000){
            return ((this.edgeProfile + this.groupPrice())*4) - addOns;         
        }else if(length <= 5000 && length > 4000){
            return ((this.edgeProfile + this.groupPrice())*5) - addOns;         
        }
    }
```

Comment: He's trying to call `groupPrice` from `price` as well

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to get around this?

Comment: @LukeTurnbull It's the same problem as in `console.log`. You are not calling the function. Add `()`

Comment: As, so you can call a method within a method exactly the same as normally calling it? - Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: @LukeTurnbull I made change in this.price method I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: @LukeTurnbull Yes, you call a method within a method by calling it ;-) As long as you can reference a function, you can call it by appending `()`

Comment: Yes , I also forgot to add this. to all my method - Fixed it now, Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're calling the function, append with () otherwise you're just referencing the function.

Comment: @Luke Turnbull No worries - we all make school boy errors. It comes with staring at the same code for too long. BTW - you don't need to break the switch statement if you're returning. It's dead code.

Comment: Oh, well that saves some typying! Thanks pal.